# Android Kotlin Coroutines Freeze

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have come across an interesting coroutines freeze that I have simplified into the following problem:

```
//running on main thread
runBlocking {
   lifecycleScope.launch {
      delay(1000)
   }.join()
}
```

This causes the main thread to freeze indefinitely. I assume it is because of the following sequence of events:

1. Queue to launch
2. Call to join, pass main thread to coroutine pool
3. Call to launch
4. Call to delay, pass main thread to coroutine pool
5. Thread moves back to join and waits
6. Delay never finishes because it does not have a thread available?

Correct me if I am misunderstanding the above logic. What is a reasonable pattern to avoid this from happening? I understand the running blocking on the main thread is not a good idea, but deeper in the code it seems odd that you can accidentally freeze a single thread coroutine in this manner.

Comment: It's not odd that you can accidentally deadlock a thread using `runBlocking`. What's odd is using `runBlocking` at all. It has extremely narrow use cases outside of the `main()` function of a JVM app.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that seems like a reasonable answer, still odd to me that this would end up holding the main thread somewhere

Comment: Why it is odd to you? Even the name of `runBlocking()` function says it blocks the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an explanation about what exactly causes the deadlock.

Any code anywhere in your app that is running on the Main thread is actually running from a message that has been sent to the Main Looper's queue of messages to process on the main thread.

The way `Dispatchers.Main` works is that it essentially sends pieces of coroutines as Runnable messages to an Android `Handler` that is backed by the Main `Looper`. Messages sent to the Main Looper can only be processed one at a time.

Inside your `runBlocking` call, your `join()` call is suspending until its associated coroutine finishes. That coroutine has been submitted to the main Looper. The Looper cannot process any messages in its queue until the current message returns. The current message is whichever one ran the method on the main thread that you called `runBlocking` from.

`runBlocking` is waiting on `join()` to return. `join()` is waiting for its coroutine to get processed by the Looper. The Looper is waiting on `runBlocking` to return.

I saw you mentioned in a comment that it works with GlobalScope. This is because GlobalScope uses `Dispatchers.Default` and `lifecycleScope` uses `Dispatchers.Main` (unless you modify the default context when launching the coroutine).

Comment: Yes, this is my understanding as well. I'm only concerned because OP below my answer said that they observe `delay()` to be invoked. Which I believe should not happen.

Comment: @broot, well technically, `lifecycleScope` uses `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, so it might be executing code up to the first suspend function call before it actually gets submitted to the looper and `launch` returns a `Job`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense!

Comment: I feel that this is the most concise explanation as it delves into the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of calling `runBlocking` on the main thread (which defeats the idea of even using coroutines); the order of events might not matter, when the top-most instruction already stalls the thread. It's always `GlobalScope` vs. `CoroutineScope` vs. `lifecycleScope` ...where `lifecycleScope.launch` can be used with different dispatchers:

- `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`: Launches a coroutine within the `lifecycleScope`  provided by AndroidX. **Coroutine gets cancelled as soon as lifecycle is invalidated** (i.e. user navigates away from a fragment). Uses `Dispatchers.IO` as thread pool.
- `lifecycleScope.launch`: Same as above, but uses `Dispatchers.Main` if not specified.

Therefore I'd assume, the behavior also may stem from dispatching with `Dispatchers.Main`.

Answer (score 1):

It is even simpler than you think. Because of `runBlocking()`, `join()` doesn't return the thread to the event loop, so the `launch()` block never starts executing - deadlock.

Actually... this is not entirely true. `join()` returns the thread to the pool, but not to the one we think about. `runBlocking()` starts its own event loop using the caller thread. From the outside of `runBlocking()` the thread seems to be constantly blocked, but in the inside it loops and can suspend. Anyway, from the perspective of `lifecycleScope` the main thread is blocked and it can't launch anything on it.

> What is a reasonable pattern to avoid this from happening?

Do not call `runBlocking()` on the main thread. Coroutines are no exception here. We should not run blocking IO or other kind of blocking operations on the main thread and that includes `runBlocking()`.

Comment: I guess I am still wondering where it blocks and why? launch does start, we can log and see that `delay` is started but never completes.

Comment: This is because the lifecycle is never being invalided. Doing strange things gives you strange results.

Comment: @MartinZeitler ahh when I replace lifecycleScope with GlobalScope it is fine, this is more in line with my expectations. I still am interested in what mechanism causes the lifecycleScope to freeze like this though?

Comment: @HaydenKai Hmm, are you sure about the log before `delay()`? I tried to simulate the same case using single threaded dispatcher and it doesn't even get inside `launch()` (code: https://pl.kotl.in/DnhbHYPSb ). I probably miss something here.